# RecyclerView get item when it leaves screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I get object from recyclerview when it leaves screen while scrolling? For example I have `note with id 11` how can I get this note id whenever it leaves screen?

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: From your adapter.

Comment: I need to get id of object whenever it reaches top of the screen

Comment: Top of the screen means it is still visible and hasn't left the screen

Comment: So how can I detect whenever that object leaves the screen and it's not visible anymore

Comment: `RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled(VH holder)`

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it:

```
Boolean upScrolling;  
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            LinearLayoutManager mgr = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            int topPosition = mgr.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            /// your code

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    if (dy < 0) {
                        upScrolling = true;
                    } else if (dy > 0) {
                        upScrolling = false;
                    } 
        }
    });
```

After scrolling up, in the listener you get the 1st visible item. At the position *your code* you write the code to check if the 1st visible item is the one below the item you want. If this is the case then you get the time it went off the screen.
Edited to check if it scrolls up or down.